# How to find the minimum surface area enclosed by a boundary C?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am currently learning multivariable calculus and I was wondering how can I find the minimum surface area enclosed by a boundary C, as shown below.(This is not a exam/homework question, just something I thought of for fun.)

r(t) is my take on parameterized this boundary.

Any help would be appreciated
[image: AreaOfCurve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather old question, and has a name -- it's called *Plateau's problem*, and Fred Almgren wrote a nice little book about it back in the 1970s or so; there's probably lots of new stuff to consider since that time, but it's a good introduction.

Anyhow, that's the keyword that you want to use for searching. No one can give you a complete answer here in the space of one math stackexchange answer. The general problem of optimization over classes of functions like this comes under the heading of "calculus of variations," which gives you another term to search.

Stand warned: some of the notation varies from hideous (at worst) to baffling (at best) until you've used it for a while.

One more thing: you talk about "the" surface of least area, but there are curves, like the seam on a baseball, for which there is no unique minimal spanning surface -- there may be two or more minimal surfaces!